# How to solve Environment Variables with $ Character?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I have a Environment Variables:

```
 "PWD=uNfob$bA5052433"
```

When I print PWD out it always:

```
'uNfob'
```

I have tried :

```
'PWD=uNfob$bA5052433'
```

or

```
PWD='uNfob$bA5052433'
```

all not work,any suggestion ?

Comment: That last one works for me. What are you getting when you `echo $PWD`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing exactly. Are those the values of an environment variable or commands you run on a shell? If so, what shell and what commands are you running exactly? Also, I hope that is not your real password for anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by 2 steps:

```
1.use single quotes 'PWD=uNfob$bA5052433'
2.add '/' 'PWD=uNfob/$bA5052433'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
VAR='aaa$bbb'
echo $VAR

aaa$bbb
```

`PWD` is a special shell variable that represents the current directory. You might want to use someting else.